# Need date values which are 90 days or more from current date in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a dimension [Date].[Last Met].
I need to pull out values which are more than 90 days from current date using MDX.
Please suggest the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this:

```
FILTER
    (
     [Date].[Last Met].MEMBERS,
     Datediff("d",[Date].[Last Met].CurrentMember.Name, Format(Now(),'yyyyMMdd') <=90
    )
```

A much more elegant option would be to create a calculated column in DSV called `RollingLast90Days`, and using SQL `datediff` logic to assign it 1/0. Once in place, you would need to just have a slicer :

```
     ...WHERE ([Time].[[RollingLast90Days].&[1])
```

Above is based on asumption you would process cube daily. If not apply the same logic in a calculated measure.

```
IIF(
Datediff("d",[Date].[Last Met].CurrentMember.Name, Format(Now(),'yyyyMMdd') <=90,
1,
null)
```

and then using this slicer on `HAVING` or in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i have tried the filter query with Now function.
However the problem which I am facing is that the attribute has values like 
2015-11-13
2015-10-02.
So the now() function is looking for the present date and since it is not finding anything it evaluates to NULL resulting in no Filter condition working on the attribute.
My requirement is such that for eg. the attribute has values like 
2015-12-11
2015-12-01
2015-10-01
2015-09-15.
I need to get records which are 90 days older when compared to today's date so my output should be only 2015-09-15 as per the above records.